# Restrict GWT client class to get cached

Tags: gwt

Is there any way to restrict our GWT client class to get cached in browser as when it compile it gets cached with *.cache.js file.

I don't want it to get cached how do I restrict it

Answer (score 3):

The name of the generated .cache.js file is different after each compilation so it won't be cached. Do you have any reason to think otherwise ?

I've been hot-swapping GWT-generated war since this morning and I never had to clear my browser's cache.

Comment: Yes I have a specific sinero where in I create a war and deploy on two different tomcat instance, and open both the instance in same browser. If I do so I'm not able to communicate with my HTTPServlet via gwt requestbuilder. There should be two GET calls while sending the request first one executes fine but for second it dosen't even make a GET call.

Comment: @TarishSaini And? What's the problem?

Comment: Could you compare the two URL the RequestBuilder is querying ?

Comment: Yes using chrome debugger I did that, but for first it gives me URL for GET request but for second It dosent give any URL. Might be some cache related issue.

Comment: Could you put a log just before the call to the RequestBuilder and output the URL argument to the console, then write it here ? There must be one, otherwise check the way you construct that URL.

Comment: I got whats the issue in that:

Comment: I got whats the issue is: when we try to load our GWT module with the same war deployed on 2 tomcat insatnces, cache.js file with the same name gets loaded on the browser now its ambiguty for browser to know which js file to call, Since the first call gets complete and it modifies the js objects, it takes the same JS file with modified URL having different host and port, It fails to retrive the servlet since it is on different host and port.

Comment: But you could see in your browser that the .nocache.js was downloaded once in each window right ? I'd rather say that the way the url is constructed should be based on the URL showing up in your browser. It looks like it works in a different way, ignoring which server the application is deployed on. The .nocache.js is not modified once you receive a GET request result. Please post the two URL that you are sending GET request to and/or the code that's building those URLs.